# how to get posts in fb:api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

**fb function and scopes**

```
function Login()
```

**fb login response**        {

```
       FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                getUserInfo();
            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
//scopes
            }
         },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});

    }
```

**i'm getting name and other info here**

```
function getUserInfo() {
        FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email',function(response) {

      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

    });
```

**How can get user posts here ?**

Comment: You can use "/me/feed" to get posts, but your app needs user_posts permission.

Comment: can i use this with same fields which is in my code?or i have to create one more function?

Comment: You can request the basic user data and their latest posts in one request, if you use the [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/#fieldexpansion) syntax.

Comment: can't be fixed. can you post answer code here?